# Fill Missing Financial Time Series Data From One Table to Another with SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

This is part of an open source python project I am building on Github, it can be found here:

[fxcmminer](https://github.com/JamesKBowler/fxcmminer)

I have lots of financial time series data from FXCM which is full of gaps. The gaps need to be filled by other data in the database and I was woundering if someone could help me out?

The databases and tables were created using a python script which can be found [here](https://github.com/JamesKBowler/fxcmminer/blob/master/fxcmminer_v1.0/db_manager.py)

A snipping from the code is below.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS fxcm_bar_GBPUSD;                                            
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fxcm_bar_GBPUSD.tbl_GBPUSD_m1;
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `bidopen` DECIMAL(19,6) NULL,
  `bidhigh` DECIMAL(19,6) NULL,
  `bidlow` DECIMAL(19,6) NULL,
  `bidclose` DECIMAL(19,6) NULL,
  `askopen` DECIMAL(19,6) NULL,
  `askhigh` DECIMAL(19,6) NULL,
  `asklow` DECIMAL(19,6) NULL,
  `askclose` DECIMAL(19,6) NULL,
  `volume` BIGINT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`))
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The below two queries are for the 1 minute and 5 minutes intervals, as you can see in the 1 minute there are many data points missing. Before I resort to 'predicting' the values, there are some data points in the 5 minute table that could help fill the gaps.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from fxcm_bar_GBPUSD.tbl_GBPUSD_m1 where date >= "2002-3-31 17:00:00" and date <= "2002-3-31 18:00:00";
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| date                | bidopen  | bidhigh  | bidlow   | bidclose | askopen  | askhigh  | asklow   | askclose | volume |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| 2002-03-31 17:01:00 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.426200 | 1.426200 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:15:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425700 | 1.425800 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.426000 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:17:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:20:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425700 | 1.425500 | 1.425700 | 1.425900 | 1.426000 | 1.425800 | 1.426000 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:22:00 | 1.425700 | 1.425800 | 1.425700 | 1.425800 | 1.426000 | 1.426100 | 1.426000 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:24:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:29:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:31:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:48:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.425200 | 1.425200 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425500 | 1.425500 |      0 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select * from fxcm_bar_GBPUSD.tbl_GBPUSD_m5 where date >= "2002-3-31 17:00:00" and date <= "2002-3-31 18:00:00";
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| date                | bidopen  | bidhigh  | bidlow   | bidclose | askopen  | askhigh  | asklow   | askclose | volume |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| 2002-03-31 17:00:00 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.426200 | 1.426200 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:15:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:25:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:30:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:45:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.425200 | 1.425200 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425500 | 1.425500 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 18:00:00 | 1.425200 | 1.425500 | 1.425200 | 1.425500 | 1.425500 | 1.425800 | 1.425500 | 1.425800 |      0 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Like wise there are data points in the 1 minute table, that could fill missing data points of the 5 minute table.

After the tables have swapped there values they would look like this.

```
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| date                | bidopen  | bidhigh  | bidlow   | bidclose | askopen  | askhigh  | asklow   | askclose | volume |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| 2002-03-31 17:00:00 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.426200 | 1.426200 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:01:00 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.426200 | 1.426200 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:15:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425700 | 1.425800 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.426000 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:17:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:20:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425700 | 1.425500 | 1.425700 | 1.425900 | 1.426000 | 1.425800 | 1.426000 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:22:00 | 1.425700 | 1.425800 | 1.425700 | 1.425800 | 1.426000 | 1.426100 | 1.426000 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:24:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:25:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:29:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:30:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:31:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:45:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.425200 | 1.425200 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425500 | 1.425500 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:48:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.425200 | 1.425200 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425500 | 1.425500 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 18:00:00 | 1.425200 | 1.425500 | 1.425200 | 1.425500 | 1.425500 | 1.425800 | 1.425500 | 1.425800 |      0 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+


+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| date                | bidopen  | bidhigh  | bidlow   | bidclose | askopen  | askhigh  | asklow   | askclose | volume |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
| 2002-03-31 17:00:00 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.426200 | 1.426200 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:15:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:20:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425700 | 1.425500 | 1.425700 | 1.425900 | 1.426000 | 1.425800 | 1.426000 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:25:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425800 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.426100 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:30:00 | 1.425800 | 1.425800 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.426100 | 1.426100 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 17:45:00 | 1.425600 | 1.425600 | 1.425200 | 1.425200 | 1.425900 | 1.425900 | 1.425500 | 1.425500 |      0 |
| 2002-03-31 18:00:00 | 1.425200 | 1.425500 | 1.425200 | 1.425500 | 1.425500 | 1.425800 | 1.425500 | 1.425800 |      0 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+
```

There are still missing data points, however the data that has just been filled is real data.

I will then perform further data interpolation outside of the database using python, which is not part of the this question.

How would I have both of these tables exchange and insert the missing rows without cross contamination?

Thank-you

Comment: You have described the starting data you have. What do you want to make of it? How should the result look like? Also, please add the CREATE TABLE definition for the tables involved including their attributes. (Otherwise we will be programming in the dark)

Comment: And when is an interval considered to be compromised? What do you want to achieve? More details please. Detailed requirements.

Comment: @flutter I have edited my question, thanks

Comment: Would it be sufficient, if you had two tables named minutes1 and minutes5, which had both the schema (date, text) with date as unique primary key? And your question is then, to just add missing data into each other, if such a date does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you want. Could be wrong though. Difficult to say.

All your bid* data is not affected by any operation, so your question seems to be equivalent to just tables with a date (here tp) to identify rows and some data, here abstracted as text (here t) for convenience.

```
-- Example setup  
CREATE TABLE minutes1 (tp datetime, t text, PRIMARY KEY (tp));  
CREATE TABLE minutes5 (tp datetime, t text, PRIMARY KEY (tp));  

-- keep common data 00:00:00 as is  
INSERT INTO minutes1 VALUES ('2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'a');  
INSERT INTO minutes1 VALUES ('2017-01-01 00:01:00', 'b');  
-- add this 00:05:00 to minutes5 because would fit there and is missing  
INSERT INTO minutes1 VALUES ('2017-01-01 00:05:00', 'c');  
-- keep common data for 00:00:00 as is  
INSERT INTO minutes5 VALUES ('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '1');  
-- add this 00:10:00 to minutes1 because would fit there and is missing  
INSERT INTO minutes5 VALUES ('2017-01-01 00:10:00', '2');  

table minutes1  
tp                    | t  
'2017-01-01 00:00:00' | 'a'
'2017-01-01 00:01:00' | 'b'
'2017-01-01 00:05:00' | 'c'

table minutes5
tp                    | t
'2017-01-01 00:00:00' | '1'
'2017-01-01 00:10:00' | '2'
```

**Solution strategy**

We never change existing data in either table. Only insert missing pieces. Therefore cross contamination cannot happen:

- If the data is in both, then nothing happens.
- If the data is in one, but not the other, it can be inserted safely.
- If the data is in neither one, then we have nothing to transfer anyway.
- Granularity is always respected.

  - Inserts from 5 minute steps down into 1 minute steps are always possible.
  - Inserts from 1 minute steps up into 5 minute steps are only possible, if the step n is evenly divisible by 5.

**Transfer from minutes5 into minutes1**

This is always safe, if data is missing in minutes1, because minutes1 has smaller granularity than minutes5.

```
INSERT INTO minutes1  
SELECT * FROM minutes5  
WHERE date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM minutes1);
```

**Transfer from minutes1 into minutes5**

We cannot insert a date with 2 minutes into the table with a granularity of 5 minute steps.
We use the same strategy as above, with an additional `WHERE MINUTE(date) % 5 = 0` clause to check the granularity.

```
INSERT INTO minutes5  
SELECT * FROM minutes1  
WHERE MINUTE(date) % 5 = 0 AND date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM minutes5);
```

**Expected result**

```
SELECT * FROM minutes1;  
SELECT * FROM minutes5;  

table minutes1  
tp                    | t  
'2017-01-01 00:00:00' | 'a'
'2017-01-01 00:01:00' | 'b'  -- not added to minutes5
'2017-01-01 00:05:00' | 'c'
'2017-01-01 00:10:00' | '2'  -- copied from minutes5

table minutes5
tp                    | t
'2017-01-01 00:00:00' | '1'
'2017-01-01 00:10:00' | '2'
'2017-01-01 00:05:00' | 'c'  -- copied from minutes1
```

**Remarks**

You might consider adding a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to guarantee the integrity of your `minutes5` table with `MINUTE(date) % 5 = 0`. Please consult your MariaDB manual for instructions on how to achieve this. Probably something like this.

```
ALTER TABLE minutes5  
ADD CONSTRAINT check_minutes5_is_multiple_of_5  
CHECK (MINUTE(date) % 5 = 0);
```

Comment: Instead of `MINUTE(date)` you can also use `EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM date)` according to [MariaDB Date and Time](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/extract/) :)

Comment: wow, thanks for this looks great! I am just running some tests now and I will come back to you shortly

Comment: I can confirm this is working as per the question asked. I ran without `INSERT` for **Transfer from minutes5 into minutes1** and there are 64 thousand plus extra rows to be inserted.  The database contains data from Daily to Intra-day to Minutely and once all these are combined, each table will be just that little bit more complete : ). So thank you for your help!